# Print multi-value after pattern match in single line

Tags: bash

I have single line output as follows

```
"ng-num_sta" : 5 , 
"ng-num_sta" : 10 ,
"ng-num_sta" : 15 , 
"ng-num_sta" : 3 , 
xyz value : 1 , blah blah, single line
```

I want to get values for string `ng-num_sta` only

example:

```
5
10
15
3
```

I have tried following but its printing pattern matching only,

```
 cat myfile.txt | grep -Po '(ng-user-num_sta.)[^\s]*'
```

OUTPUT:

```
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: have tried following but its printing pattern matching only,

cat myfile.txt | grep -Po '(ng-user-num_sta.)[^\s]*'

OUTPUT:

ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"
ng-user-num_sta"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regEx` match is incorrect, use `GNU grep` with `-P`, `PCRE` mode enabled as and `\K` to ignore the pattern match up-to that point.

```
grep -oP '\"ng-num_sta\" : \K[^ ]*' file
5
10
15
3
```

Check the `regEx` [here](https://regex101.com/r/G1TnRq/2).

Comment: I suggest to replace `,` by one blank to get rid of the trailing blank.

Answer (score 0):

Is this alright?

```
awk '$1 ~ /ng-num_sta/{print $3}' file

5
10
15
3
```

Comment: OP wants to get values for `ng-num_sta` only... your giving values for _lines that don't match `xyz`_; while your answer gives the correct output in the small example provided by the OP, you're certainly not answering the question. What I mean is this: what if I answered `printf '%s\n' 5 10 15 3`. It would give the correct answer in the case of the OP's example, but that would certainly not be a valid answer.